# zipfile password not accepted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying  to extract a zip file with password, in this case the password is 12345, but when I try the extractall, it catches the exeption of wrong password. And I don't know if it might be helpful, I am using python 3.7.

I put the b"12345" because I have tried it but I also have tried other things such as:

```
   pwd = "12345".encode('cp850','replace')

   pwd = "12345".encode(utf-8)

   I also tried to use a variable instead if "12345" which was the main ide
```

The code is:

```
   try:       
       zipArchive.extractall(pwd=b"12345")
       print("\nPassword found: ", password.decode('utf8'))
   except RuntimeError as a:
       print("\nWrong password: ", password.decode('utf8'))
       print(a)
```

The error message I got:

```
  Bad password for file <ZipInfo filename='coral.png' compress_type=99external_attr=0x20 file_size=1368829 compress_size=1345029>
```

By the way coral.png is the unique file that is in the zip file

Comment: `zipArchive.extractall(pwd=b"12345")` should do the trick normally. What is the OS you're using? Are you sure the password is `12345`?

Comment: Windows 10, yes I tried to extract the zip file several times mannually and I am sure of the password. I can not understand what's going wrong

Comment: How did you create the file? Is only one file affected or can you reproduce this with different files and passwords?

Comment: I created the file through winrar interface, but I seleccted .zip of course. I can't do it with any zip file created in my pc, although a friend of mine created zips in ubuntu and with those all works perfectly. It might be a problem due to the use of winrar interface to create it.